# How do I make a USB "hub" from an LG monitor connected to a PC

Tags: usb, hdmi, macbook, desktop-computer, external-display

I have an LG HDR 4K monitor connected to a MacBook Air laptop via USB Type-C, and a PC via HDMI. I also have a keyboard and speakers connected to the same monitor via USB.

Since the monitor and the MacBook are connected via USB Type-C, the monitor and the MacBook make a "pair" meaning that the monitor charges the laptop, works as a second screen, and connects the keyboard and speakers to the laptop seamlessly.

However, those speakers and the keyboard connected to the monitor are not visible to the PC since the monitor and the PC are connected via HDMI.

My question is if there is a way to avoid unplugging the USB devices connected to the monitor and plug them into the PC every time I switch to it, i.e. work the same as it does with a MacBook?

Comment: USB devices are point ot point. To share them you would need a dedicted KVM or a USB 'switch; which switches from being a hub connected to one PC to, disconnect and switch to the other. I am using one sunch device. Since Sunday. So not enough experience to recommed it yet. (even assuming sunch product recommendation were wecomed on SU)

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple solution that would retain the ability to charge the laptop from the display.

Connecting two computers to one display, keyboard, and mouse is a relatively common thing to do and there's a wide variety of products for this purpose.  The problem is that these KVM switches expect both computers to attach to the display with the same kind of interfaces.  Getting a KVM switch that supports 4K HDMI, speakers, keyboard, and mouse is easy enough, but then you will need a dock for the laptop to split out the USB-C to HDMI, USB-A, and power passthrough for a USB-C power supply.  The KVM switch could likely be had for about $150 and the dock for about $50.

I have seen displays with a built-in KVM switch so check the manual on if your display supports this before you go buy anything.  The displays I've seen with a built-in KVM switch will have a USB-C port to connect one computer and USB-B to connect the other computer.  As you discovered there must be a USB data path for the keyboard and mouse to work on both computers, and to get that means two USB ports, if you don't have two ports to connect two computers then there's no KVM switch in the display.